# AWS Cloudfront very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

My website images are loading slow while using cloudfront, what option or practices should i use to increase loading speed of image.I have a nextjs application which is stored in AWS S3 and deployed over AWS cloudfront. The app is very slow on AWS. What is a bestpractise to increase the speed?

Comment: What size are your pictures? Which edges do you have enabled for CloudFront and are you testing from a location which is covered by one of those edges? How fast is the internet connection you are testing with?

Comment: Can you show us your measurements so we can see how 'slow' it is?

Answer (score 1):

First thing make sure that you have set up you caching policy right. It could just be that you are not caching your resources correctly.

Inspect a request directly to S3 and check if any cache-control: no-cache header is begin set as Cloudfront will respect backend sent headers.
If that is the case check the documentation to set it up correctly.

Here's the documentation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html).

If the caching is set up correctly, check you image size, large image will take time to download. The only way to speed this up is to compress the images before serving them over the internet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 things which you can check for this issue.

**1. Check Bucket region**

Check the location of your S3 bucket. Suppose if you get large number of requests from India then try to keep your S3 bucket in the Indian regions like mumbai.

**2. Seperate behaviour for images**

As you said your images are loading slow, create seperate cloudfront behaviours for images.

Example
If you have .jpg images in your bucket then create a seperate behaviour as "*.jpg" in cloudfront behaviour section

**3. Caching for the images behaviour**

Since images are static content, enabling caching for images behaviour. You can configure it for 2 to 10 days or for 1 month based on requirement.

**4. Setting image size**

Keep track on your image size. Try to use images with average size like 100 to 500 kb.

Check for these 4 things and I think this would reduce your images loadtime.